# why splice remove a data in array from all variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently learning javascript,
i create an array and then define it in 2 variable arrayBase and arrayData
but when i use splice, all the data in other variable also get removed.
I don't know what happen

```js
const arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
const arrayBase=arr
let max=0
let min=0
let arrayData=arr

for(let i = 0; i<arrayBase.length;i++){
    console.log(i,arrayBase)
    let x
    arrayData.splice(i,1)
    arrayData.forEach((item)=>x=x+item)

    if(x>max){
        max=x
    }
    if(min<x){
        min=x
    }
    arrayDataabc=arr
 }
```

Can anyone help explain why splice make other variable array get removed?
Thanks before!

Comment: What do you think `arrayBase=arr` does?

Comment: `const arrayBase=[...arr];`

Comment: i think `arrayBase=arr` create a new array based on my first array

Answer (score 0):

In Javasxript Objects (even arrays are object) are mutable means it can be modified .

when you assign the objects (even array) to the new variable , the new variables point to the same objects.

Comment: so how to create a new object based on my first array? destructring it? `const arrayBase=[...arr];`

Comment: Yes you can copy array using
const arrayBase = [...arr];